# extracting patterns in egrep and placing them at start of line in output file?

Tags: grep

Is there a way in grep/egrep to extract tricky patterns from this text, insert them at the start of a line with its line remainder, so that it looks like the following?

Raw text that has been extracted from many files which have the word "nonspecific". Now I need to organize these so that the names start at the start of the line so that they are easier to read. It would help to insert a blank line in between them as well but that may be not possible in egrep?

**Input:**

```
SofasCouchesChairs/Type1234567.xml:Nonspecific Couch-W ISSUESTablesDesks/Type123765.xml:Nonspecific Tables issues BedsDivans/Type4567345.xml:Nonspecific bed abnormalitiesBedBugs/Type2893993.xml:Nonspecific bugs in the spring boxes related to the mattressBed_Sofas/Type1317994.xml:Nonspecific WR abnormalities these are from Radios_TV/Type1274978.xml:radiation perhaps with nonspecific cell phones and cell towers Cabinets_TelephoneWires/Type1299691.xml:DATA:all kinds of nonspecific cell phone wave changes, with a
```

**Expected output:**

```
SofasCouchesChairs/Type1234567.xml:Nonspecific Couch-W ISSUES

TablesDesks/Type123765.xml:Nonspecific Tables issues 

BedsDivans/Type4567345.xml:Nonspecific bed abnormalities

BedBugs/Type2893993.xml:Nonspecific bugs in the spring boxes related to the mattress

Bed_Sofas/Type1317994.xml:Nonspecific WR abnormalities these are from 

Radios_TV/Type1274978.xml:radiation perhaps with nonspecific cell phones and cell towers

Cabinets_TelephoneWires/Type1299691.xml:DATA:all kinds of nonspecific cell phone wave changes, with a
```

Comment: `I need to organize these so that the names start at the start of the line`.     Could you explain what constitutes a name?

Comment: @djf Yes, I'm sorry. The organized text did not appear as I wanted them to in the box above. They got jumbled together. Each name looks like "BedBugs/Type2893993.xml:" and should start at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @nlper: How should we handle, for example, `abnormalitiesBedBugs/Type2893993.xml:` or `ISSUESTablesDesks/Type123765.xml:`?

Comment: @nlper: When you extracted your raw text from many files which have the word "nonspecific", were you able to set some sort of delimiter? In your case, a null delimiter makes downstream manipulation much much harder.

Comment: @nlper: Also, would you mind formatting your input/expected output? You can use a code block.

Comment: @steve: I looked at the faq to see how to do a code block but could not find any info. The two examples you ask about in your first comment are the problem. I've been manually going through the examples to make each line begin with the name, which e.g., is BedBugs/Type2893993.xml: (and the rest of the line)

Comment: and the next line would start with: TablesDesks/Type123765.xml: (and the rest of the line). If it is of any help, I think there may be a newline character at the end of each line that the egrep originally extracted from the other files. So e.g. there may be an invisible newline character at the end of "SofasCouchesChairs/Type1234567.xml:Nonspecific Couch-W ISSUES". I noticed little box characters when I copied these examples to notepad. But they still run into each other as in:"ISSUESTablesDesks/Type123765.xml:" even if there is a newline character after ISSUES. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @steve: I did not set any delimiter when I was extracting "nonspecific" other than non-case sensitive. I just needed the remainder of the line to see what kind of context nonspecific appeared in, and I needed the names.

Comment: @nlper: I'm a little confused about what your input looks like. You can indent text with 4 spaces to start a code block. I've attempted to update your input, but I may not be understanding correctly. Please adjust accordingly. I do think however that your problem may stem from the copying to notepad. You should avoid this. I am assuming you are searching for multiple patterns. If you are calling grep multiple times, simply append to your file i.e: `grep "pattern" input >> output`. Or you can search for multiple patterns like this: `grep -P "yourexpression|anotherexpression" input > output.txt`

Comment: @steve Thank you very much, Steve. You were correct. The problem was opening up the grep output in notepad. When I open it up in notepad++, all the newline characters are accessed and everything is lined up exactly like the way you adjusted the output above. I really appreciate your perseverance in replying to my question. I am going to count your answer as correct. But how do I mark it as a correct answer since it is in the comment box?

Comment: @nlper: No worries :-)  I've added an answer with some (hopefully) useful info for you. BTW, my editor of choice is `vim`. This may interest you: http://linuxconfig.org/Vim_Tutorial

Comment: @steve: thank you again. I will try all your suggestions. I was wondering how to insert spaces for readability. I am using cygwin which will hopefully accommodate sed. I have heard of vim. I will take a look at the tutorial when I get a chance at work. thanks a million again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments; the input is actually:

```
SofasCouchesChairs/Type1234567.xml:Nonspecific Couch-W ISSUES
TablesDesks/Type123765.xml:Nonspecific Tables issues 
BedsDivans/Type4567345.xml:Nonspecific bed abnormalities
BedBugs/Type2893993.xml:Nonspecific bugs in the spring boxes related to the mattress
Bed_Sofas/Type1317994.xml:Nonspecific WR abnormalities these are from 
Radios_TV/Type1274978.xml:radiation perhaps with nonspecific cell phones and cell towers
Cabinets_TelephoneWires/Type1299691.xml:DATA:all kinds of nonspecific cell phone wave changes, with a
```

You can double space your output to match the expected output:

```
sed G input.txt > output.txt
```

An aside, if your are trying to make things easier to read, you can experiment with the number of G's. For example, this will triple space your file:

```
sed G;G input.txt > output.txt
```

Also, to make the changes directly to your file, you can using the `-i` flag (this saves us from having to unnecessarily create `output.txt`):

```
sed -i G input.txt
```